# Compiling OpenFace written in C++ with Emscripten, get the warnings: "unresolved symbol"

Tags: javascript, c++, emscripten

When compiling in bitcode `em++ FaceLandmarkVid.cpp -std=c++11 -o OpenFace.bc` I get no warnings. When I compile from the bitcode to JavaScript `em++ OpenFace.bc source.bc -o OpneFace.js` I get the following:

```
warning: unresolved symbol: _ZN12GazeAnalysis12EstimateGazeERKN16LandmarkDetector4CLNFERN2cv7Point3_IfEEffffb
warning: unresolved symbol: _ZN16LandmarkDetector19FaceModelParametersC1ERNSt3__26vectorINS1_12basic_stringIcNS1_11char_
traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEENS6_IS8_EEEE
warning: unresolved symbol: _ZN16LandmarkDetector22DetectLandmarksInVideoERKN2cv4Mat_IhEERNS_4CLNFERNS_19FaceModelParame
tersE
warning: unresolved symbol: _ZN16LandmarkDetector23Calculate3DEyeLandmarksERKNS_4CLNFEdddd
warning: unresolved symbol: _ZN16LandmarkDetector24CalculateAllEyeLandmarksERKNS_4CLNFE
warning: unresolved symbol: _ZN16LandmarkDetector4CLNF5ResetEv
warning: unresolved symbol: _ZN16LandmarkDetector4CLNFC1ENSt3__212basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEE
E
warning: unresolved symbol: _ZN16LandmarkDetector7GetPoseERKNS_4CLNFEffff
warning: unresolved symbol: _ZN2cv12VideoCaptureC1Ev
warning: unresolved symbol: _ZN2cv12VideoCaptureD1Ev
warning: unresolved symbol: _ZN2cv17CascadeClassifierD1Ev
warning: unresolved symbol: _ZN2cv3Mat10deallocateEv
warning: unresolved symbol: _ZN2cv8fastFreeEPv
warning: unresolved symbol: _ZN5boost6system15system_categoryEv
warning: unresolved symbol: _ZN5boost6system16generic_categoryEv
warning: unresolved symbol: _ZN9Utilities10FpsTracker6GetFPSEv
warning: unresolved symbol: _ZN9Utilities10FpsTracker8AddFrameEv
warning: unresolved symbol: _ZN9Utilities10FpsTrackerC1Ev
warning: unresolved symbol: _ZN9Utilities10Visualizer15ShowObservationEv
warning: unresolved symbol: _ZN9Utilities10Visualizer18SetObservationGazeERKN2cv7Point3_IfEES5_RKNSt3__26vectorINS1_6Poi
nt_IdEENS6_9allocatorIS9_EEEERKNS7_INS2_IdEENSA_ISF_EEEEd
warning: unresolved symbol: _ZN9Utilities10Visualizer18SetObservationPoseERKN2cv3VecIdLi6EEEd
warning: unresolved symbol: _ZN9Utilities10Visualizer23SetObservationLandmarksERKN2cv4Mat_IdEEdRKNS2_IiEE
warning: unresolved symbol: _ZN9Utilities10Visualizer6SetFpsEd
warning: unresolved symbol: _ZN9Utilities10Visualizer8SetImageERKN2cv3MatEffff
warning: unresolved symbol: _ZN9Utilities10VisualizerC1Ebbb
warning: unresolved symbol: _ZN9Utilities15SequenceCapture12GetGrayFrameEv
warning: unresolved symbol: _ZN9Utilities15SequenceCapture12GetNextFrameEv
warning: unresolved symbol: _ZN9Utilities15SequenceCapture4OpenERNSt3__26vectorINS1_12basic_stringIcNS1_11char_traitsIcE
ENS1_9allocatorIcEEEENS6_IS8_EEEE
warning: unresolved symbol: _ZN9Utilities15SequenceCaptureD1Ev
warning: unresolved symbol: _ZNK16LandmarkDetector4CLNF15GetVisibilitiesEv`
```

Could that mean that a function has a declaration but no definition?